# Why separating the data in training and test sets is not feasible in unsupervised learning problem?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, finite-mixture-model

Based on my understanding:

> Unsupervised learning problems are modeling data with no labels. Hence, we try to cluster a given data into clusters.

> Supervised learning problems are modeling data with known labels. Hence, we try to
> predict the label for a new point.

My question is, why splitting the data into training and test sets is not feasible for unsupervised learning problems? I think separating the data into training and test sets is used to test the accuracy of the fitted model.

Comment: You can separate the data into train and test sets. But then the question is, what metric are you evaluating on the test set? If there are no labels then certainly you cannot evaluate accuracy.

Comment: @RyanVolpi is right. It can make sense to do it, but it isn't so obviously how then this can be used. Here is a paper where we discuss what could be done splitting the data in unsupervised classification: https://wires.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/widm.1444

Comment: @RyanVolpi Thanks. So much appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks. It is really helpful. Your help is so much appreciated.